# What happens if I use two cards with the same sort of effect?

Tags: pocket-mine

When I am choosing my cards for a dig, I know I get three cards. Usually, I end up with three different ones, but I started to wonder - if I have a mission to collect, say, a lot of coal, can I stack card effects to make it easier?

For example, can I use both a Coal Galore card that says "100% more Coal blocks. 12% of Coal blocks are explosive" and a More Coal card that says "100% more Coal blocks", and have the effects combine? Or does it just select the "better" card?

Answer (score 0):

The effects combine. I sadly cannot prove this beyond the fact that I used to play pocket-mine and know from playing.